# Call a state modifying function from a view function

Tags: solidity

Contract 1:

```
contract ViewContract{
    
    function callStateModifyingFunc() public view {
        require(address(this).balance >= gasleft(), "Insufficient balance in contract to cover gas costs.");
        modifyContract.setName("Blovario");
    }
}
```

Contract2 :

```
contract ModifyContract {
    string name;

    function setName(string newName){
        name = newName;
    }
}
```

I skipped all imports etc...

I got this error :

> TypeError: Function declared as view, but this expression
> (potentially) modifies the state and thus requires non-payable (the
> default) or payable.

But I did not find any way to call a state modifier function from a view function... Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change state variables inside functions with `view` modifier. This because, when you use `view` function, the compiler expects to read a specific value from storage and not change it.